# Cannot read close text reader VB using StreamReader

Tags: .net, vb.net, streamreader

I'm creating a program Guessing game where the words are stored in a text file and retrieved via StreamReader while creating it I want to ask the user if he wants to play again, but when the user types Y there's an exception occurred, d " cannot read close text reader" , this will not happen unless I will not integrate playing again (means the program will exit)

Imports System
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim word As StreamReader
    word = New StreamReader("Words.txt")


    Dim charAns, c1, c2, c3, pAgain As Char
    Dim num1, num2, num3, count As Integer
    Dim prevCount As Integer = 0
    Dim wrdGst As String = " "
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim rand As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 20)
    Dim bool As Boolean
    bool = True


    Console.WriteLine("Guess My Word")
    While bool
        num1 = 0
        num2 = 0
        num3 = 0
        count = 0
        prevCount = 0
        'loop file using rand number 
        For i = 0 To rand
            If i <> rand Then
                wrdGst = word.ReadLine() ->>>>>> HERE'S WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURED
            End If
        Next
        word.Close()
        Console.WriteLine(wrdGst)

        'Generate ng 3 rand number then check each other if same
        While num1 = num2 Or num1 = num3 Or num2 = num3
            num1 = rnd.Next(wrdGst.Length - 1)
            num2 = rnd.Next(wrdGst.Length - 1)
            num3 = rnd.Next(wrdGst.Length - 1)
            Continue While
        End While

        'char to be guest
        c1 = wrdGst.Chars(num1)
        c2 = wrdGst.Chars(num2)
        c3 = wrdGst.Chars(num3)

        'convert the word in array char
        Dim charArr(wrdGst.Length() - 1) As Char
        Console.WriteLine("Word To Guess")
        'replace the missing char with _
        For ctr = 0 To wrdGst.Length - 1
            charArr(ctr) = wrdGst.Chars(ctr)
            charArr(num1) = "?"
            charArr(num2) = "?"
            charArr(num3) = "?"
            'print
            Console.Write(charArr(ctr))
        Next

        'compare if the char is correct
        While True
            If count = 3 Then


            Else
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.Write("Enter a Latter: ")
                charAns = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper

                If charAns = c1 Then
                    charArr(num1) = charAns
                    count += 1
                End If

                If charAns = c2 Then
                    charArr(num2) = charAns
                    count += 1
                End If

                If charAns = c3 Then
                    charArr(num3) = charAns
                    count += 1
                End If
                'check if correct answer 
                If count < 3 Then

                    If count.Equals(prevCount) Then
                        Console.WriteLine(" WRONGS!!!!! XXXXXXXXXXXXX ")
                        Console.WriteLine(New String(charArr))

                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine(" Nicee!!!!! :) :) :)")
                        Console.WriteLine(New String(charArr))
                    End If
                    prevCount = count
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine(" Goodjob!!! You guess the correct answer")
                    Exit While
                End If
            End If
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("Final Answer: " + New String(charArr))
        Console.WriteLine("Play Again? Y/N: ")
        pAgain = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper
        If pAgain = "Y" Then
            Continue While
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for Playing.........")
            bool = False

        End If
    End While
    word.Close()
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: During our while loop you are closing the reader (_word.Close()_) after your _loop file using rand number_

Comment: Even I remove the close() its still the same sir hmmm.

Comment: So you maybe reached end of file (Readline starts at position of first round of your game). So close and open the file again.